# How to make shell script non blocking?

Tags: shell, pipe, sh, blocking

Just a simple question:
Why following one-linear not working? How to make IO non blocking?

```
$ while true; do date; sleep 1; done | tail -f
```

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish. `tail -f` is intended to follow changes to a file. When you pipe input into it it behaves just like normal tail, which means that it can't determine what to output until it reaches the end of the input, which only never happens since it is an infinite loop.

Comment: Thank you, I realized what my misunderstanding is, `tail` command is going to grab the tail first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not with non-blocking IO; it's with your choice of `tail`.

This prints out each line with a colon (all of them):

```
while true; do date; sleep 1; done | grep :
```

The problem with `tail` is that it goes to the last 10 ten lines *and then* starts following. But in your case, it never reaches the end, so it can't print the last ten.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want to do is continually replace the last line with the date you could do this:

```
while true; do echo -en "\r"`date`; sleep 1; done
```